# Site not loading jQuery image carousel in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have my site http://alexjoneswork.com/ working fine in chrome,mozilla,safari but it doesn't seem to load the jquery image carousel in IE (which is basically the site). It's using a great image carousel plugin: http://buildinternet.com/2011/07/supersized-3-2-fullscreen-jquery-slideshow/
which does seem to load in IE but for some reason my site (using the same scripts) isn't working. Anything stand out in the code?

Comment: Which version(s) of IE? If this is IE8 try adding @width and @height on img element or maybe `max-width: 100%`

Answer (score 2):

I checked it on IE9 and indeed it shows it as if it's eternally loading without rendering the website. From what I've read in the comment sections of the plugins link you mentioned until January 2012 all who had IE issues have not solved them yet.

But, in my opinion you should contact the developers of the plugin also.

Also, check your DOCTYPE and meta tags inside since it has:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ">
```

and

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

You can replace the DOCTYPE with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and I'd suggest to remove the compatibility with IE8 tag.

Answer (score 1):

If not working in any versions of IE, try adding DOCTYPE declaration for universal compatibility:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Comment: Ya I've tried a couple different doctypes but none seem to fix the issue. Here's the initial plugin source http://www.alexjoneswork.com/slideshow.zip It's the 'carousel.html' one. I've gone over it and tried to cross check my source with but nothing stick out. Any thoughts?

Comment: @jonur tried your doctype too as well as this one <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" not working with IE still